# No Wi-Fi adapter found Ubuntu 18.04 regardless of any action

Tags: networking, 18.04, drivers, internet, iwlwifi

I am really struggling here to make wi-fi on my laptop work. It's so weird, it worked well, but then there was a system update or something and after that it just stopped. It says No Wi-Fi adapter found Ubuntu 18.04, however I am able to connect with a wire. So at first, I tried all possible things described in the internet, nothing worked, so I just reinstalled ubuntu, and the wi-fi worked fine... until now (it's been exactly 1 day). I haven't done anything that would possibly break it so bad.

So, I've tried searching in the internet again, and found these 2 websites:

1. https://easylinuxtipsproject.blogspot.com/p/intel-wifi.html
2. https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-no-wifi-option-on-ubuntu-18-04-and-16-04/

As you have probably guessed, it didn't work. As far as I understand I have an iwlwifi intel module which is responsible for my wifi, but it's drunk or whatever happened to it. Nothing seems promisable, so I ended up being here, so you guys are pretty much my last hope in fighting ubuntu with its endless problems.

I am posting the output that I think is useful below:

**$ lsmod | grep iwlwifi:**

```
iwlwifi               385024  0
cfg80211              700416  1 iwlwifi
compat                 16384  2 iwlwifi,cfg80211
```

**$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3:**

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0084]
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:f1a8] (rev 03)
```

**$ rfkill list all:**

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

**$ sudo lshw -C network:**

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 15
       serial: 0c:9d:92:04:fc:89
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.68.125 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:55 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fc904000-fc904fff memory:fc900000-fc903fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 1a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:fc800000-fc803fff
```

**$ sudo ifconfig wlan0:** (weird)

```
wlan0: error fetching interface information: Device not found
```

**$ sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl:**

```
[    2.292973] Loading modules backported from iwlwifi
[    2.292974] iwlwifi-stack-public:master:8613:3ae69204
[    2.361826] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.582168] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:03:00.0 failed with error -110
```

I think that is all needed, but I can surely post any other output per request.

I would gratefully appreciate some help!

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl`  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 oh yeah that one, I completely forgot about it! I have added the output. Thanks! I've tried it before and I am not sure why loading iwlwifi fails.

Comment: Is this a dual-boot with Windows? https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled

Comment: @chili555 yes I do have a dual-boot with Windows, lemme try that. Thanks!

Comment: @chili555 It solved the problem! It sees the adapter now, however it works weirdly, it turns on and turns off without seeing networks. I have probably broken something when installing the backport iwlwifi. Do you have any tips on how to go back to where I was before trying it all out? Shall I reisntall ubuntu again, or is there any easier option? Thanks a lot, I appreciate it!

Comment: Please try: `sudo apt purge backport-iwlwifi-dkms` and reboot.

Comment: @chili555 yep it works now! I can't believe it was that easy, but seemed so impossible. You are a great human! Thanks a lot for your assistance.

Comment: I shall write an answer that I hope you will accept. Glad it’s working!

Comment: @chili555 yeah, sure! I will mark it as Solution, go ahead :) Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since yours is a dual-boot installation alongside Windows, I recommend that you disable Fast Startup in Windows. Reference: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled

Next, the backport package is often known, including in my own case, to actually *degrade* performance. I recommend that you remove it:

```
sudo apt purge backport-iwlwifi-dkms
```

Reboot.